# A barcode from cl-pdf bar-codes.lisp is invalid?

Tags: common-lisp, barcode

I have printed many barcodes using [cl-pdf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mbattyani/cl-pdf/master/bar-codes.lisp).

The barcode for "16537" doesn't scan. Others (e.g., "11537") do. I produced them using:

```
    (pdf::tester "16537" "/test1.pdf")
    (pdf::tester "11537" "/test2.pdf")
```

Comment: Confirmed, I can't scan the first one either (I had to compile `tester` that is `+nil` commented in the source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to an incorrect value in cl-pdf in bar-codes.lisp in *table*. In that table, the Code B character for value 64 is \#' but should be \#`. This causes incorrect codes when encoding a string which contains \#' including if \#' is the check character. For "16537", \#' is the check character.

I put this as an issue [here](https://github.com/mbattyani/cl-pdf/issues/33)

Update: 2/18/22 Fixed by Marc Battyani